# Realmでauto incrementを設定する

Tags: swift, realm

テキストフィールドに入力された文字をデータベースに登録していく際、`primaryKey`に`autoincrement`を設定したいのですが、`swift`ではどうやって設定すればいいでしょうか？

```
override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
}
```

色々調べてみたのですが、上記ようにprimaryKeyを設定する方法しか見つけることができませんでした。どなたか分かる方に教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

現在RealmにはAuto Incrementの機能はありませんので、必要なら自分でその仕組みを実装する必要があります。
（Auto Incrementの機能についての要望は多いのでタスクには挙がっていますが、まだその機能がいつリリースされるかは未定です。）

もし、IDがユニークであればよくて、連続していたり、順番に増加していく必要がないのであれば、UUIDをIDとして利用することをお勧めします。
iOSでUUIDを生成するには`NSUUID`クラスを利用すると簡単です。

連番のIDが必要なのであれば、連番を自分で管理する必要があります。簡単なのは連番を別にクラス変数などで管理することです。この方法なら毎回レコード数をカウントするクエリを発行せずに済む、などのメリットがあります。

もし、このモデルが複数のスレッドから使用される場合は、`nextPrimaryKey()`のようなメソッドをスレッドセーフになるように注意深く実装する必要があります。

こちらの同様の質問も参考にしてください。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252432/how-do-i-set-a-auto-increment-key-in-realm/26257616#26257616

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。Realmにはまだautoincrementはないのですね。今回僕が作りたい機能では連番のIDが必要なので、クラス変数で管理する方法でプログラムを組んでみたいと思います。ありがとうございました。